# video call using android

Tags: android, video-capture, sip

I want to develop a app which uses 3G for video calling where secondary camera will be use for video call.

Is that possible to make video call? If it is possible please give me some reference or tutorial.

Comment: sip protocol is one of the option. look for sipdroid open source project.

Answer (score 2):

you should look for SIP protocol stack in android. There are various open source projects out there. look for [SipDroid](http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/source/checkout), [IMSDroid](http://code.google.com/p/imsdroid/) is also a good example. And [Sip Api](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/package-summary.html) is also available in Android after API level 9.

Answer (score 1):

Another one worth looking at is the [CSipSimple project](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/). It is using pjsua as SIP library. The video call is developed in a [branch of the project](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/source/browse/#svn/branches/video).

I have not tested it yet but it seems to work according to an issue. The issue starts getting interesting from [comment 27](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/issues/detail?id=112#c27) onwards since after that video calls seem to be working.

Check it out and look into it. It will probably take some time to find your way around the code at first.

Comment: Just helpful to start as a newbie.