# SDK for Android video call

Tags: android, video

I am developing an application in android in which I want to make video calls for free over ip. Is there any SDK available so that I can add the Video call functionality in my app.

I looked over Linphone and many other like that but they are providing the core programming, coded at very high level and I am beginner in android so very tough it is to understand those code.

So.. if there is any SDK available by which I could be able to make video call through my app.. please tell me.. a Big thanks to all in advance.. :)

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664260/video-call-using-android

Answer (score 1):

CSip is a native SIP library that has a port to Android: https://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/ They have a video feature in alpha stage. You will need to handle the NAT traversal and all of that yourself.

You may also want to check out the Adobe's AIR 3.5 runtime which has many p2p including video built in. The up side is that you can write it once and deploy to iPhone + Android. There are some downsides to using a non-native SDK.